# how to show an error when in appbrowser does not load error phonegap

Tags: javascript, phonegap, inappbrowser

i am developing an application and loading an hosted application using  the inapp browser plugin cordova-plugin-inappbrowser

I have gotten most of the functionalities to work but i am unable to get the part of loading an error message when he url does not load, it dosent just work and shows me an error message of the url where i have hosted my application instead.

Which could be embarrassing.

please i need help on this

This is what am working with below thanks for ur potential responses

```
    // my child browser code, the main source of my app content

function fire(){

  var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://####################', '_blank', 'location=no,zoom=no,hardwareback=yes,clearsessioncache=yes,clearcache=no');

var myCallback = function(event) { alert(event.url); }

ref.addEventListener('loadstart', inAppBrowserbLoadStart);

ref.addEventListener('loadstop', inAppBrowserbLoadStop);

ref.addEventListener('loaderror', loadErrorCallBack);

ref.addEventListener('exit', inAppBrowserbClose);

}

function loadErrorCallBack(params) {



    $('#status-message').text("");



    var scriptErrorMesssage =

       "alert('Sorry we cannot open that page. Message from the server is : "

       + params.message + "');"



    inAppBrowserRef.executeScript({ code: scriptErrorMesssage }, executeScriptCallBack);



    inAppBrowserRef.close();



    inAppBrowserRef = undefined;



}



function executeScriptCallBack(params) {





    if (params[0] == null) {





        $('#status-message').text(

           "Sorry we couldn't open that page. Message from the server is : '"

           + params.message + "'");

    }





}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is generally fine, but you have no control over the title of the `alert()` function. You can use some other techniques to display the error message. For example, you can use a `div`:

```
function loadErrorCallBack(params) {
  $('#status-message').text("");
  var scriptErrorMesssage = createMsg('Sorry we cannot open that page. Message from the server is: '
                          + params.message);
  inAppBrowserRef.executeScript({
    code: scriptErrorMesssage
  }, executeScriptCallBack);
  inAppBrowserRef.close();
  inAppBrowserRef = undefined;
}

function createMsg(msg) {
  return 'var div = document.createElement("div");'
       + 'div.style.position = "absolute";'
       + 'div.style.top = "50%";'
       + 'div.style.left = "50%";'
       + 'div.style.width = "100px";'
       + 'div.style.height = "100px";'
       + 'div.style.color = "#f00";'
       + 'div.innerHTML = "' + msg + '";'
       + 'document.appendChild(div);'
}
```

Comment: thanks, ill update as specified and get back to u, much appreciated

Comment: hi just tried your update and its still tghe same, after iv compiled my app and tested again, can u by chance give me a basic usage of how u av implemented this so i can compile and test, would really appreciate tanks

Comment: If you're still seeing a error message with the URL of your project, that means you have another `alert()` than the one in your question. Search for it and comment it out. Or you have an exception that you didn't handle (i.e. put between `try...catch`), in which case you'll have to debug your app to see what's going on.

Comment: hi can u pls take a look at my full html code https://paste.ofcode.org/gEaUeMfvRAG5b3MKcYcgq6

Comment: The line `var myCallback = function(event) { alert(event.url); }` needs a semicolon at the end. And you can delete it since it is not used. The inAppBrowser cannot be called before the `deviceready` event. You're calling it after 8 seconds which may or may not be enough, so call it in `deviceready` instead.

Comment: Then I'm afraid you will have to post your entire code. We don't have a crystal ball to guess what can be wrong in code we don't see. Alternatively, you can start with basic code and start adding to it bit by bit until you get the error, then you will know which bit is causing it.

Comment: ok thanks for the index page https://pastebin.com/ZdhNsPCM, and for the included javascript in the index page  which is index.js https://pastebin.com/v993CNpU thanks once again